# How to prevent BSON deserialization instantiating members in a class?

Tags: deserialization, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I have a class that instantiates it's own internal objects and changes internal properties on them which aren't serialized.  One for example is setting the parent object.

How do you prevent the BSON driver from instantiating these particular members on a class, since the main class for the document already does this?

I have read the serialization information (quite minimal) and checked what BSON attributes are available but I don't see anything that looks like it will help.

Comment: This situation is quite broad. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get round my issue I refactored the properties to instantiate what they needed on the object created by the BSON deserialization process.